# VBScript instantiate class and populate variables at the same time

Tags: class, arraylist, vbscript, asp-classic

If i have my own class in VBScript:

```
class TestClass
    public var1
    public var2
end class
```

I can instantiate and populate as such:

```
dim classVar
set classVar = new TestClass
classVar.var1 = "test1"
classVar.var2 = "test2"
```

My question is, is there a one-liner for instantiating and populating?  My hope is to be able to do this while adding the class to a list:

```
dim listVar
set listVar = CreateObject( "System.Collections.ArrayList" )

listVar.add new TestClass ("test" "test2")
```

Is this possible in VBScript?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, VBScript/VB6/VBA do not support *constructors* for classes.

You can use a Factory:

```
function MakeTestClass(a, b, c)
   set MakeTestClass = new TestClass
   MakeTestClass.var1 = a
   MakeTestClass.var2 = b
end function

listVar.add MakeTestClass(11, 22, 33)
```

Comment: Answered the question and gave an alternative.  This will work perfect for my purposes.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Or one (or more) special init (member) functions returning Me:

```
>> Class cC
>>   Private n
>>   Public Function init(p)
>>     n = p
>>     Set init = Me
>>   End Function
>>   Public Function toString()
>>     toString = "cC object: " & n
>>   End Function
>> End Class
>> WScript.Echo New cC.init(4711).toString()
>>
cC object: 4711
>>
```